# Access and return data from restful webservice to jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this restful web service where i actually return a list<> in c#. Now i need to access it with jquery and ajax(this part done) what i haven't and i couldn't do is how to traverse the data and print it one by one on the jquery side. Any help will be much appreciated. UPDATE: having this code on my rest web service. Can you give me a sample code for the $.each function? because i can't seem to make it work. THANK YOU.

```
       List<Inventory> IService1.GetInventory()
    {
        List<Inventory> list = new List<Inventory>(); using (SqlConnection testconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            if(testconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                testconn.Open();
            }

            using(SqlCommand testcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from inventoryitem",testconn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = testcmd.ExecuteReader();
                while( reader.Read())
                {
                    Inventory testObj = new Inventory();
                    testObj.InventoryName = reader["StandardCost"].ToString();
                    list.Add(testObj);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to Serialize it as JSON:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Then iterate over it with an $.each() in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: do i need to serialize it? because i already have a responseFormat of webMessageFormat.JSON on it so on the browser it returns it as json. Can i ask a specific code for $.each()? thank you.

Comment: `$.each(your_collection, function (i, collection_item) { alert(collection_item) }`

Comment: Sir, can i ask for a edited code of mine? because this code ( based from yours )  $.each(result, function (i, val) { alert(val); }); is not working.